# Moore-Penrose g-inverse question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I am attempting to show that *C*(**I − A<sup>+</sup>A**) = *N*(**A**)

The column space of the quantity above equals the null space of **A**, where **I** is the identity matrix, **A** is an n x m matrix and **A<sup>+</sup>** is the Moore-Penrose g-inverse of **A**.

I have been attempting to change the left side around using identities and the conditions of a generalized inverse. Can I maybe use **A<sup>+</sup>A** = **I**? If I use that then I just have *C*(**0**) = *N*(**A**). I mean, I know the zero vector is always in the null space but that seems trivially easy.

Is there some other direction I should be going with this?

Comment: In general, $A^{+} A \neq I$ unless $A$ has linearly independent columns.

Comment: Maybe I can use the conditions of a Moore-Penrose g-inverse? So, A = A(A+)A and substituting that in the column space expression we have C(I - (A+)A) = C(I - (A+)(A(A+)A). Now I can use the fact that A(A+) is symmetric, and A(A+)  (A+)'A'. So, plugging that in the column space expression, we have C(I - (A+)(A+)'A'A) = C(I - I^2) = C(I - I) = C(0). I don't know how to format everything in a comment, I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @theGRUMBER Please use LaTeX in your comments for readability.

Comment: @theGRUMBER Which definition of the MP inverse are you familiar with? In some way, you need to arrive at the fact that $A^+A$ is an orthogonal projection matrix.

Comment: The one in my text is: 1. A = A(A+)A, 2. A+ = (A+)A(A+), 3. A(A+) is symmetric, 4. (A+)A is symmetric. I will have to learn how to use Latex to format in this comment box because this is just awful.

Comment: @theGRUMBER Regarding Latex: for example, typing `$A = AA^+A$` in the comment box results in $A = AA^+A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim 1:** $A^+A$ is an orthogonal projection

*Proof:* It suffices to note that $P = A^+A$ is symmetric (which is given as a property of the MP inverse) and show that $P^2 = P$. Indeed, we see that
$$
P^2 = A^+AA^+A = A^+(AA^+A) = A^+A = P. \qquad \square
$$

**Claim 2:** The row space of $P = A^+A$ is equal to the row space of $A$ (or equivalently, the null space of $P$ is equal to the null space of $A$)

*Proof:* The row space of $PQ$ is always a subspace of the row space of $Q$. Thus, the row space of $P = A^+A$ is a subspace of the row space of $A$ and the row space of $A = AP$ is a subspace of the row space of $P$. So, the two row spaces are equal. $\hspace{1 cm}\square$

From there, it suffices to note that the null space is the orthogonal complement of the row space. Thus, $I - P$ must be the projection onto the null space of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! That helped me a lot. I appreciate the formatting tip, also.